# Completeness preserved under isometric isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite dimensional normed spaces. Let $D: X \rightarrow Y$ be an isometric isomorphism. If $X$ is complete is $Y$ complete?

Any hints on how to start this would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Let $(y_n)$ be a Caucy sequence in Y. Then you should be able to show, as $D$ is norm-preserving, that  $D^{-1}(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $X$, and hence converges to some $x \in X$. Now you should be able to use the norm-preserving property of $D$ again to show that $(x_n)$ converges to $D(x)$. Does this help?

Comment: $D^{-1}(x_n)$ converges because $X$ is complete. Does $y_n=D^{-1}(x_n)$?